# Ionic serve with SSL

Tags: facebook, vue.js, ionic-framework, https, facebook-login

I have been trying to test my Ionic app with ionic *--ssl serve --host 'localhost'*.

Unfortunately, it still does not work. When I try to connect https://localhost:8000, it says a SSL error.

Is there something more I should do to make it work? I need https to be able to test Facebook login because Facebook does not allow API calls from http pages.

Comment: I noticed that in the development mode, Facebook API works from a http page even though it gives a warning to the console. So no need to solve this SSL issue anymore. In the production, the web app will anyway be hosted on Https.